# Defining constants used in multiple Python scripts

Tags: python-3.x

I have two scripts (written in Python 3), let's call them `A.py` and `B.py`, which I execute at different times. Both scripts rely on the same set of constants I defined, but I will vary their values from time to time. It's clunky though to keep updating the constants in **both** `A.py` and `B.py`.

Therefore, I'm curious if it is possible to create one script in which I can define the constants used by `A.py` and `B.py`, **and** choose to execute either `A.py` or `B.py`.

My failed attempt:

I tried importing `A.py` and `B.py` as modules into the script where the constants were defined and running the relevant script from there, but the constants were not found in the namespaces of `A.py` and `B.py` when imported, so it didn't work.

Comment: "...set of _constants_ <...> I will _vary their values_ (?!) from time to time" - constants are _constant_, their values aren't supposed to be changed. Also, what prevents you from importing the script with the constants into both `A.py` and `B.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it much more complicated than it has to be... Just define your constants in a distinct file (let's name it "constants.py") and import it in your A.py and B.py scripts. You just have to make sure that "constants.py"i is accessible in your `sys.path` (the modules search path), but this will be the case if you have all three files in the same directory.